# How to check for a corrupted PDF in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf

I have a PDF file which I downloaded from a server, sometimes the users uploads a corrupted PDF and I need to check if my application can open such a file or not.

So is there a built-in way I could use to check for the PDF corruption ? If not is there a free lightweight PDF framework that I could use to view or checking the corruption ?

**Note: Currently I am opening PDF files on a UIWebView.**

Comment: Corrupted how? Compete junk or only certain defects in detail?

Comment: Well, I am not sure which part of the file is corrupted. I knew that it is corrupted when I tried to open it with a PDF reader (Adobe Reader for example).
In my case I only see a white page when opening that file, so I want to inform the user that the file is corrupted like a normal PDF reader would do.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I've found the solution using the CoreGraphics PDF drawing APIs.
Thanks for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12637982/429962).

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"A_Corrupted_PDF" ofType:@"pdf"];
NSData *data = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:path];

CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithCFData((__bridge CFDataRef)data);
CGPDFDocumentRef document = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithProvider(provider);

if (document == nil) {
    NSLog(@"The PDF is corrupted");
}
CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(document);
```

Comment: this is not at all working :( is there any alternative way to check whether is corrupted or not?